# CellPaintingEvent of DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to highlight List of strings in my dataGrid view. For this purpose, I used the existing code that highlights a keyword in dataGridView. but resultant code only higlights last occurrence of the list (i.e. last record fetched). 
Here is What I've tried

```
            private void dvg_ClauseSent_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string sw in HighlightStrings) // HighlightStringsis the list of string containing all strings I need to highlight in DataGrid view
        {
            int strt = 0;
            int cnt = -1;
            int idx = -1;
            TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.Default | TextFormatFlags.NoPrefix;
            if ((((e.RowIndex >= 0) && (e.ColumnIndex >= 0))))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, true);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sw))
                {
                    string val = e.FormattedValue.ToString();
                    int sindx = val.IndexOf(sw);
                    if ((sindx >= 0))
                    {
                        while (strt != -1)
                        {
                            strt = val.IndexOf(sw, idx + 1);
                            cnt += 1;
                            idx = strt;
                            if (strt != -1)
                            {
                                if (strt != 0 && ((strt + sw.Length) != val.Length))
                                {
                                    Rectangle hl_rect = new Rectangle();
                                    hl_rect.Y = (e.CellBounds.Y + 2);
                                    hl_rect.Height = (e.CellBounds.Height - 5);
                                    // find the size of the text before the search word
                                    // and the size of the search word
                                  // paint the background behind the search word
                                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(hl_brush, hl_rect);
                                    hl_brush.Dispose();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // paint the content as usual
            e.PaintContent(e.CellBounds);
        }
    }
```

**Attached ScreenShots**

Following screenshot shows the strings that should appear as highligted in dataGridView
http://i42.tinypic.com/2dtrea1.png

Part of strings enclosed in ANGLE BRACKET followed/preceeded by |* / *| should be appeared as highlighted but only last entry is being highlighted.
http://i39.tinypic.com/30cbw9l.png

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: your problem should have been described clearly with just 1 screen shot, you don't have enough reputation but you can refer a link to your screen shot easily.

Comment: Updated question to include screen shots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has this strange thing:

```
Rectangle hl_rect = new Rectangle();
hl_rect.Y = (e.CellBounds.Y + 2);
hl_rect.Height = (e.CellBounds.Height - 5);
```

You don't even initialize the `X` and the `Width` (hence they will be empty by default). So how could it be rendered???

I would like to talk this to everyone who will be asking questions, **please post your actual code**. Don't try simplifying it if you don't understand how wrong it is after being simplified. Except the code above, I don't find any thing which may cause the issue (it's of course not tested, just a quick scan). I've tried writing another code for you, also tested. The problem is we have to draw the string and measure the string together so that the *Text Bound* can be determined exactly. The `TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias` should also be used, although sometimes it works without that. The drawn text may look a little *blurry* however it can be partially eliminated by using a large font, the larger the better. Here is the code for you.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, 
                                        DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e) {
     if (e.RowIndex > -1 && e.ColumnIndex > -1 && e.Value != null) {
         string value = e.Value.ToString();
         foreach (var s in HighlightStrings) {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < value.Length && (i = value.IndexOf(s,i))!=-1) {
              if (!e.Handled){
                  e.Handled = true;
                  e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, true);
               }                        
               StringFormat sf = StringFormat.GenericTypographic;
               sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center; 
               RectangleF textBounds = GetTextBounds(e.Graphics, 
                                                     value, i, s.Length,
                                                     e.CellBounds, 
                                                     e.CellStyle.Font, sf);
              //highlight it
              e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, textBounds);
              i += s.Length;
              using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(e.CellStyle.ForeColor)) {
                 //draw string , don't use PaintContent
                 e.Graphics.DrawString(value, e.CellStyle.Font, brush,
                                       e.CellBounds, sf);
              }
            }
         }                
     }
 }
 public RectangleF GetTextBounds(Graphics g, string text, 
                                 int subIndex, int subLength, 
                                 RectangleF layout, 
                                 Font font, StringFormat sf) {
      var charRange = new CharacterRange(0, text.Length);
      var subCharRange = new CharacterRange(subIndex, subLength);
      sf.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(new[]{ charRange, subCharRange });
      var regions = g.MeasureCharacterRanges(text, font, layout, sf);
      return regions.Length < 2 ? RectangleF.Empty : regions[1].GetBounds(g);
 }
```

**NOTE**: The reason we have to use `DrawString` is as I said to measure the `TextBound` exactly. If you have some way to measure it exactly without having to draw the string yourself, you can use `PaintContent`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked like charm. I will implement your suggestions from now on. Can you kindly recommend some tutorials regarding that? I've studied msdn documentation but it was not that good for me

Comment: @user1816551 You can search for some keywords like `GDI+`, in fact I don't use any tutorial, just from sample code, try it yourself ... You can find a lot of sample code of such kind in **codeproject.com**. That's a very great site to download sample code and learn from them.